# Does Square have an API for accepting payments?

Tags: mobile, payment, square

Square Connect looks perfect but it's only for reporting purposes. We want to build on top of Square's payment platform to accept payment within our application through Square.

Answer (score 3):

*Update (2016-03-30):*

Square now provides APIs for accepting online and in-person payments. See [this article](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/connect-v2-released-2016-03/) for details.

*Original answer:*

Not at this time. From the [Square Help Center](https://squareup.com/help/en-us/article/3853-square-connect-api#additional-api-uses):

> We do not currently offer an API for e-commerce solutions, but if we do in the future, we’ll be sure to announce it.

Comment: This is no longer true. Square released a public API: https://squareup.com/developers

Answer (score 1):

They do offer an API for commerce, but they limit who can use it and it looks like it may just be for iOS.

> The Commerce API is currently available only to approved partners. If you're interested in using the Commerce API to integrate your iOS app with Square Register, please contact partners@squareup.com.

More info in [the Square API Documentation](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api#commerce-api-overview).

Comment: This is no longer true. Square released a public API: https://squareup.com/developers

Answer (score 0):

I used the url scheme for the Square Register app to open it from my app. All it does is open the app though, and there is no way to send a payment. The link only shows up in my app if the user has the Square Register app installed on their phone.

Perhaps Square's developer can comment on this method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Square Register API (only for iOS apps). The Square Register API  lets your iOS app integrate with Square Register to let merchants accept payments. And it is currently available only to approved developers. If you're interested in using the Register API to integrate your iOS app with Square Register, you need to contact them first. Please see in detail docs [here](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/#navsection-register)